# Multi-stream real-time predection with jetson nano

Tags: video-streaming, object-detection, video-processing, nvidia-jetson-nano

I used gstreamer + opencv for decoding 12 multi-streams ip camera with 480p5.
The predection times of model in nano are 100ms and 130ms for batch_size=1 and batch_size=2.
I used threads for H264 HW decoding. and I want to know how to handle this problem for 12 cameras at the same time? I want to know in Nvidia demo shown 8 streams 1080p30 processed at the same time, how do they thandle this challange. I guess they don’t feed inputs of 8 stream to model at the same time, right? I think they feed the first two cameras as batch_size=2 and then feed to model and then second two cameras to model as sequentioal and so on , right? if so, assume they feed each of two cameras to model as same time and also they decode 8 streams at the same time, so if we feed first two camera into model in the time of T1, the frames of rest cameras (i.e 3-8) are rejected in the time of T1 for processing?

Comment: They use their DeepStream SDK. Here's the link. https://developer.nvidia.com/deepstream-sdk

Comment: Yes, I know. in your opinion, Is it possible to use deepstream sdk in our custom projects?

Comment: Absolutely, Deepstream supports custom models/projects.